# select a column from a text file using windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, text-files

I have a text file which has below data

```
162       y    1   0     518       home47              1     
163       y    1   0     520       home41              1     
164       y    1   0     522       home43              1     
165       y    1   0     524       home45              1     
166       y    1   0     526       home46              1     
169       y    1   0     531       home50              1     
170       y    1   0     533       home52              1     
171       y    1   0     535       home54              1     
172       y    1   0     537       home56              1     
173       y    1   0     539       home58              1
```

I would like to copy 6th column data from below (home47 to home58) into another text file using **windows batch file**. How can I perform that

I have tried with below command which is mentioned in another questions, but not working for me

```
CMD /f:off
FOR /f "tokens=6 delims=  " %B in (TabFile.txt) do @echo %B  >> 2ColFile.txt  
CMD /f:on
```

Comment: you tried this in batch file or in the command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
break>2ColFile.txt
for /f "tokens=6 delims=     " %%c in (TabFile.txt) do (
    echo %%c
)>>2ColFile.txt
```

**EDIT** Have on mind that delimiters are `delims=<tab><space>` and the could be changed by stackoverflow formater.

Comment: The character after `delims=` should be a TAB character if the original file is TAB delimited.  TABs are translated to spaces in this forum.

Comment: @foxidrive - Yes.And the tab should not the last delimiter (in this case it is space - `<tab><space>`) for unknown reason tab as a last delimiter could cause a problems (I think dbenham explained this somewhere)

Comment: The default delimiters are space and tab so you can remove `delims=` to make it work without editing.